# How can I work out time difference between git tag and the original commit

Tags: git, git-tag

I am looking to work out the time difference between when a commit is made and when that commit was tagged.

This is what I have so far however the committerdate which I think this is the correct field is null.

```
git for-each-ref --format='%(taggerdate) : %(committerdate) :  %(refname)' --sort=-taggerdate --count=10 refs/tags
```

At a guess I am looking only at tags, though I cannot get it right. In an ideal world it would show the difference between the times however I can do this afterwards if it is not possible.

Comment: tags... a lightweight one or an annotated one? (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging#Annotated-Tags)

Comment: These are Annotated Tags set via team city

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The `git for-each-ref` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-for-each-ref.html) is kind of misleading:

> For commit and tag objects, the special `creatordate` and `creator` fields will correspond to the appropriate date or name-email-date tuple from the `committer` or `tagger` fields depending on the object type. These are intended for working on a mix of annotated and lightweight tags.

This does work exactly as documented: `%(creatordate)` gets the date from the `tagger` field of these annotated tags.  However, it seems to *imply* that for an annotated tag, Git might inspect the corresponding commit: if not, how would it ever get the `committer`?

In fact, `for-each-ref` never looks *directly* at an annotated tag's target object.  The mention of the `committer` field is specific to *lightweight* tags, which point to commits,<sup>1</sup> rather than annotated tag objects.  Fortunately, there's a format directive saying to "look indirectly", as it were: simply prefix the directive with `*`.<sup>2</sup>

Hence the answer is:

```
git for-each-ref \
    --format='%(taggerdate) : %(*committerdate) :  %(refname)' \
    --sort=-taggerdate --count=10 refs/tags
```

---

<sup>1</sup>Lightweight tags can point directly to trees or blobs; it's not immediately clear what happens in this case.  Probably the expansion is empty.

<sup>2</sup>Note that this only indirects *once*, so if the target of the annotated tag is another tag (or is a tree or blob), there will be no committer date field.  To really make this reliable, you probably should use a bit of shell script and resolve the tag name with the `^{}` or `^{commit}` suffix.  (The difference between these two is that `^{commit}` will *fail* if the ultimate target object is a tree or blob, while `^{}` will succeed, finding that tree or blob object.)